# Highlight selected tagged regions of Tkinter Text Widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tags

I'm using python 3.4 on a windows 7 machine.

I'm using the tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText widget with a large volume of data. I've set up different areas with tags that have different text foreground colors and this works fine. I've noticed once I do this and I select a area of text that I want to copy to the clip board that is also tagged it does not show a highlight color to reflect it's selected. I can copy it to the clip board fine, but I can't figure out how to reflect it by selection color. This only affects areas of text with tags. Is there a way to set the highlight on a tag as well or do I need to bind the tag to events and set it up myself? I tried setting the selectbackground on the widget but it only affects areas that are not tagged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you select a range of characters, tkinter will add the tag `"sel"` to the selected range.

Tags have a priority, so if character has two tags that change the background, the tag with the highest priority is the one that is used. The priority of a tag is initially determined by the order in which the tag is created. That means that every tag you create will have a priority higher than the `"sel"` tag.

The solution to your problem is to raise the priority of the `"sel"` tag so that it takes priority over your custom tags. You do this with the `tag_raise` method of the text widget.

Following is an example that illustrates the point. Notice the difference in behavior if you comment out the call to `tag_raise`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, height=10, wrap="word")
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

text.tag_configure("warning", background="red", foreground="white")
text.tag_raise("sel")

text.insert("1.0", "Danger Will Robinson! You have to manage the priority"
            " of tags to get the right effect.")
text.tag_add("warning", "1.0", "1.21")

root.mainloop()
```